# Removing prime numbers from a linked list

Tags: python, linked-list

I have a linked list that I am trying to generate a random list and then remove all of its prime numbers. This is what I have so far. I know how to find the primes I'm just not sure where to go on removing them from the list. This is my updated list, it only removes one number instead of deleting all primes.

```
import random
from linkListDef import * 

def is_prime(llist):
    number = llist[0]
    
    half = int(number / 2)
    status = True
    for count in range(2, half + 1):
        if number % count == 0:
            status = False
    return status



def main():
    llist = LinkedList()
    counter = 0

    while counter != 20:
        numbers = random.randrange(1, 101)
        counter += 1
        llist.push(numbers)
    print ("Created Linked List: ")
    llist.printList()
    llist.deleteNode(numbers)
    print ("Linked List after Deletion of primes:")
    llist.printList()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: store all prime numbers in list in a given range that will help you in two ways : First It will help you in finding next prime number and when you are done with finding all prime numbers then start deleting from linked list those prime numbers ?

Answer (score 1):

You can do a `for` loop on the now generated linked list, check the number using your `isPrime` method and running `.remove(item)` on the list, where item is the current iteration over the list